# Prove any group of order $185$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

This is my attempt. I am not sure as for its plausibility.

$Attempt$: Let $G$ be a group of order $185$. Then $G=185=5\cdot 37$. The $Sylow-p$ subgroups are unique and normal and therefore $G$ is nilpotent and so $G=P_1\times P_2$ where $P_1$ is the $Sylow-5$ normal subgroup while $P_2$ is the other. Since $5$ and $37$ are prime then $P_1$ and $P_2$ are cyclic. Is a product of cyclic groups a cyclic group? 
By what I know so far, $G$ is either isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_5\times \Bbb{Z}_{37}$ or to $\Bbb{Z}_{185}$ **but** $\Bbb{Z}_5\times \Bbb{Z}_{37}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_{185}$ because $(5,37)=1$ then what does it mean?? I am so confused...

Comment: When you arrived at $\; G=P_1\times P_2\;$ you're already done ! Yes, a direct group of cyclic groups **of coprime order** is cyclic.

Comment: Okay, you made it clear now. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Henning. Obviously I had no idea that Peter Sylow was a living person.

Answer (score 3):

As you said the $37$ group is normal, hence
$$G=\mathbb{Z}_{37}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_5.$$
Now since $|Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{37})|=36$, there are no elements of order $5$ there hence the action is trivial and 
$$G=\mathbb{Z}_{37}\times \mathbb{Z}_5.$$
Which is cyclic.

Comment: What does $\rtimes$ mean?

Comment: This is semi-direct product, look at this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product